# include/exclude mongoid attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I have a mongoid object:

```
post = Post.first
```

When I try:

```
post.attributes.each do |a|
...
end
```

this block parse all object attributes.

I need only parse 3 attributes. `post.attr1, post.attr2, post.attr3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
whitelist = %w(attr attr2 attr3)
post.attributes.select{|el| whitelist.include?(el)}.each do |key, value|
   ...
end
```

As usual, try to abstract this.

Comment: if I add `whitelist = %w(post.attr post.attr2 post.attr3)` I get an array with `["post.attr1", "post.attr2", "post.attr3"]`. I want inside array the content of this attributes. Thank you!

Comment: `white = ['_id']; User.first.attributes.select{|el, val| white.include?(el)}` and I get `{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4d5a62ac29e1676226000050')}`

Comment: edited my answer: since it gives you a hash, you have to beware of args after `do`

Answer (score 0):

`post.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at").each do |attr|
....
end`

This will also help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [`only`](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html) method which returns only the attributes specified (it also adds the `"_id"` field), for instance:

```
post = Post.only(:attr_1,:attr_2).first # This will give you something like => {"_id"=>"50cf2e893428ed5437000002", "attr_1"=>value, "attr_2"=>2012-12-21 02:00:00 UTC} 

post.attributes.each do |a|
  next if a.first == "_id" # each `a` is an array, for instance: ["_id", "50cf2e893428ed5437000002"]
  #do something with the attributes
end
```